# No output while i executing an ant via java swing code

Tags: java, php, ant

i have a java Swing code in that i need to call an Ant build at run time, here i give my code is it correct way for execution else i will do any changes, i also write my ant build here.While i executing this code there is no output my console still blank, why this problem arise if any solution is there kindly send me..thanks in advance

```
 Build.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                File buildFile = new File("child_build.xml");
                    Project p = new Project();
                    p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());     
                    DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
                    consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
                    consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
                    consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
                    p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);

                    try {
                        p.fireBuildStarted();
                        p.init();
                        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
                        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
                        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
                        p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
                        p.fireBuildFinished(null);
                    } catch (BuildException e1) {
                        //p.fireBuildFinished(e);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

My ant build is..:

```
<project basedir="." default="child_build" name="JavaSamp">
    <target name="child_build">
        <mkdir dir="classes" />
        <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe">
            <arg value="${basedir}\Child_Script.iss" />
        </exec>

        <echo message="Child_Script is executed" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have just commented this, but I dont have enough rep to do it. Are you sure you aren't getting an exception at runtime?

```
try {
                    p.fireBuildStarted();
                    p.init();
                    ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
                    p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
                    helper.parse(p, buildFile);
                    p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
                    p.fireBuildFinished(null);
                } catch (BuildException e1) {
                    //p.fireBuildFinished(e);
                }
```

This would swallow BuildExceptions that are being thrown.

Comment: I can't see what's happening in my eclipse IDE the don't show if the process is done or anything

Comment: good call on allowing exceptions, at the very least for the sake of debugging.  logging also goes a long way.